# Phonegap Build detect device in Config.xml

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

is there a way to detect smartphones or tablets right from the config.xml on Phonegap Build?
I need to lock orientation to landscape on tablets and portrait on phones.  While `<preference name="orientation" value="default" />` works in most of the cases, on iPad mini it uses portrait mode as default, and I need it to be on landscape.
The `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation` is not an option here since it works after the device is ready not giving me control of the splash screen orientation when the app starts.

Any advice would be really appreciated.